# Joint continuous random variable conditional probablity

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Okay so here is the problem: The PDF is $$f(x,y)=6(1-x)\;\; 0\leq y \leq x \leq 1$$
The question asks find $P(0<Y<0.25\;|\;X=0.5)$. I approached the problem like this $$P(0<Y<0.25\;|\;X=0.5)=\dfrac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$ $$f_X(x)=\int_0^x6(1-x)\;dy=6x(1-x)$$ so that $$\dfrac{6(1-x)}{6x(1-x)}=2$$ Now I proceeded to calculate $$\int_0^{0.25}2\;dy=0.5$$ but yet this is wrong why?

Comment: If you integrate over the whole interval, which in this case is $(0,0.5)$ you get $1$ (don't forget about the indicator $\chi\{ y < 0.5 \}$. So what makes you think its wrong?

Comment: It was counted wrong on the hw. Also why is it up to 0.5 and not 1.

Comment: Because of the indicator function. It is part of the conditional density (see my post).

Comment: Ahhh yes y is less than x. So than why is it counted wrong

Comment: Yeah, wrong homework questions can make you think you're losing your mind! Cheers!

Comment: wait I think I just read something the question asks given $x=0.5$ will that have changed everything since its little $x$ not big $X$

Comment: Is it written $P[0 < Y < 0.25]$, or was the question specified just using words, like "find the probability that $Y$ is between $0$ and $0.25$ given $x=0.5$"?

Comment: Yes that way is right

Comment: Don't tell me all I do is substitute o.5 and I'm done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density for $X$ is 
$$
  f_X(x)
= \int_0^x 6(1-x) dy
= 6x(1 - x), \ \ 0 < x < 1,
$$
so the conditional density is 
$$
  f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x)
= \frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}
= \frac{6(1-x)\chi\{ y < x \}}{6x(1-x)}
= \frac{\chi\{ y < x \}}{x}.
$$
Therefore
$$
  P[0 < Y < 0.25 \mid X = 0.5]
= \int_0^{0.25} f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid 0.5) dy
= \int_0^{0.25} \frac{1}{ 0.5} dy
= \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: My point is its wrong. I get the same thing. Also if we integrate over the entire interval the probability is greater yhan 1